# GRAPH_COMMON_NEIGHBORS returning only common neighbors without the path?

Tags: arangodb

I'm using graph common neighbours, but I only need the resulting vertexes to be returned, no need for fancy

```
[
  {collection/1:{
    collection/2:[
     {_id:3 ...},
     {_id:7 ...} 
    ]
  }
]
```

I need only the part _id:3 and _id:7 returned:

```
[
  {_id:3 ...},
  {_id:7 ...}
]
```

now I'm trying to break my head how to apprach this, as it's not list I can not FLATTEN it. Is there some hidden feature or hook to return only resulting vertices? Or should I do this manually using two GRAPH_NEIGHBORS query, as I believe that what it does in general, and limit the second query with first query?

Answer (score 1):

OK final query to return results in format I want:

```
FOR entry 
IN GRAPH_COMMON_NEIGHBORS('nodes', "node/137789480179", "node/137987398899", {direction: 'outbound'}, {direction: 'outbound'}) 
FOR a in ATTRIBUTES(entry) FOR b in ATTRIBUTES(entry[a]) RETURN entry[a][b]
```

It returns the result as I wanted, though It still may take some improvements like sorting of results by title alphabetically... I have tried and it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

the reason for the results structure is that you can call it with examples instead of single vertices. In your case of course it is obvious to which vertex pair the neighbors belong.
To sort your result you could do the following:

```
FOR entry IN GRAPH_COMMON_NEIGHBORS("nodes", "node/137789480179", "node/137987398899",      {maxDepth : 2}, {maxDepth : 2}) LET X =  entry["node/137789480179"]["node/137987398899"] FOR v      IN X SORT v.name DESC RETURN v
```

Comment: I tried it before somehow did not managed sorting to get working, will try it again as soon as will have time and hopefully it will work, on other hand I have decided to omit SORT on server side as it can be done on client-side quite easily these days :)